# CSS Make <a> appear over <ul> margin

Tags: css

I'm making a navigation bar where the the main pages can be accessed in the middle, but I want the log in button to appear to the far right.

I contain the links inside a `<ul>` element and I use `margin: auto;` to center it.

The problem occurs when I make another link outside the `<ul>` and attempt to put it on top of the margin. It appears under the navigation bar.

Here is what it looks like:
[image: Illustration]

And this is with inspect element, showing the margin from the `<ul>`
[image: With insepct element]

```css
#navBar {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 59px;
   background-color: #0040ff;
  }

     #navBar a:link, #navBar a:visited, #logInContainer a:link {
         text-decoration: none;
         background-color: #0040ff;
         color: white;
         border: 1px solid black;
         padding: 21px;
     margin: 1px;
         display: inline-block;
         list-style: none;
         font: 12px arial;
     }

     #navBar a:hover, #navBar a:active {
         background-color: #3366ff;
     }

     ul {
         width: 300px;
         margin: auto;
         text-align: center;
     }

     #logIn {
      float: right;
     }
```

```html
   <div id="navBar">
     <ul>
         <a href="index.html">Chat</a>
         <a href="status.php">Status</a>
     </ul>

     <a href="#" id="logIn"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:12px;">accessibility</i> Logg Inn</a>
 </div>
```

Html code for the navbar:

CSS code for the navbar:

So far I've tried to use z-index, all types of position and also display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to use a negative margin on the log in button:

```
#logIn {
   float: right;
   margin-top: -60px !important;
 }
```

Alternatively, you can use flexbox:

Remove `float` from `#logIn` and instead add

```
display: flex;
```

to `#navBar`

```css
#navBar {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 59px;
  background-color: #0040ff;
  display: flex;
}

#navBar a:link,
#navBar a:visited,
#logInContainer a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0040ff;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 21px;
  margin: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  font: 12px arial;
}

#navBar a:hover,
#navBar a:active {
  background-color: #3366ff;
}

ul {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <ul>
    <a href="index.html">Chat</a>
    <a href="status.php">Status</a>
  </ul>

  <a href="#" id="logIn"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:12px;">accessibility</i> Logg Inn</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add in some media queries to move things around on a smaller screen, however on desktop this'll do the trick nicely.

I've added `position: relative;` to the container `#navBar` and made the login button `position: absolute;` to the right of the element. That will position it over to the right. Then you just need to style the button accordingly to match the design you have etc.

```css
    #navBar {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 59px;
        background-color: #0040ff;
        position: relative;
    }

    #navBar a:link, #navBar a:visited, #logInContainer a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #0040ff;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 21px;
        margin: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none;
        font: 12px arial;
    }

    #navBar a:hover, #navBar a:active {
        background-color: #3366ff;
    }

    ul {
        width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #logIn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        float: right;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must display the `<ul>` as an inline-block so it wouldn't fill the whole width.

**Fix**:

replace your `ul` element's style in css file with the following:

```
ul {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```